# how to scale each dimension of an image with different ratio

Tags: graphics, scaling

I would like to scale an image file for each dimension differently for example 50% of the x dimension or 25% of the y dimension. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean `\scalebox{0.5}[0.25]{\includegraphics{file}}` or `\includegraphics{width=4cm, height=2cm]{file}` or alike?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to go about this.

In the `graphicx` package you can specify:

```
\includegraphics[width=<dim>,height=<dim>]{<file name>}
```

You can also use

```
\scalebox{<horizontal scale factor>}[<vertical scale factor>]{\includegraphics{<file name>}}
```

Also there's

```
\resizebox{<horizontal dimension>}{<vertical dimension>}{\includegraphics{<file name>}}
```