# How can I both decrease image width with 50% and increase its height to 150%?

Tags: graphics, size, resize

I've tried to use scale, but it doesn't work in this case. Have you guys any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: [how to scale each dimension of an image with different ratio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274081/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: \scalebox{<horizontal scale factor>}[<vertical scale factor>]{\includegraphics{<file name>}} worked for me. Thank you.